# What is the difference between Digital Input (S/PDIF) and Headset Microphone

Tags: sound, microphone

I have Ubuntu 18.04. I use a Plantronics headset with microphone. However, when I look at the Sound setting, two Plantronic devices appear under the Input section: Digital Input (S/PDIF) - Plantronics C320-M and Headset Microphone - Plantronics C320-M:

[image: Audio Input]

Also, when I type `pacmd list-sources` on the terminal, I only have one Plantronics input device listed.

Could anyone tell me why I have two different devices? I sometimes need to choose the Digital Input and others the Headset Microphone for the microphone to work, but I have not identified the reason.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bug occurring with USB devices: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-lib/+bug/1002952

> If you have a USB headset, or other USB device that does not have any S/PDIF output, but yet sometimes there is an extra device called "Digital Output (S/PDIF)" for that device, you're suffering from this bug.

> This bug is only for USB devices - if you have an invalid digital output for some other type of device, please file a separate bug instead.